# C Extern and Pointers

Tags: c, scope, extern

I'm new to C and i must say you i find this pointers and references thing a little bit too hard to undertand. I come from Java, so nothing of this really exists and altough once you get used to it, sometimes you are a bit lost, as i am now.

I have my header file:

```
globals.h
    typedef struct {
    float *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} points;
extern points readedPoints;
```

And i have my .c class that have a function i want to use in another file.

```
        graph.c

    #include "globals"

    points readedPoints;

    void readFile( char* filename)
    {

        ...
            ...
    // I read floats from a file and store it in my
    // readedPoints. When i print, they are all there


            for(i=0; i < readedPoints.used;++i){                
                //fprintf(stderr, "%d", graphIndices[i]);
                fprintf(stderr, " %f\n", readedPoints.array[i]);
            }
    }
```

Then in the .c in which i am using that function:

```
 init.c

#include "globals.h"

void Init(...){

   readFile("graph1.txt");

// here i do that same for-loop to check if 'readedPoints' can be accessed here, but it cant.

for(i=0; i < readedPoints.used;++i){                
            //fprintf(stderr, "%d", graphIndices[i]);
            fprintf(stderr, " %f\n", readedPoints.array[i]);
        }
}
```

I can't understand why. I declared it as extern, it was already initialized in 'graph.c' inside the readFile function, but i cannot use it in the other .c file.  Please some1 explain my why and what am i doing wrong. Thank you very much

EDIT. I get the error: access violation reading location in this last for loop

[image]

EDIT: The whole read function:

```
void readFile( char* filename)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    float n;
    int nn;
    int tags_x;

    int nrLines;
    int nrColumns;
    FILE* fp = fopen( filename, "r" );

    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERRO na leitura do ficheiro %s\n", filename );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    /* Read the number of lines */
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &nn );
    nrLines = nn;

    initFPoints(&readedPoints, nrLines*10);

    for(i = 0; i < nrLines-2;i++)
    {  
    for(j = 0; j < nrColumns;j++)
    {  
            //printf ("%f ", i);
            fscanf (fp, "%f", &n);
            //fprintf(stderr, " %f\n", n);
            insertFPoints(&readedPoints, n);
    }}
    fclose( fp );

// here it prints exactly what i want
//      for(i=0; i < readedPoints.used;++i){                
//          //fprintf(stderr, "%d", graphIndices[i]);
//          fprintf(stderr, " %f\n", readedPoints.array[i]);
//      }

}

void initFPoints(points *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = (float *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(float));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertFPoints(points *a, float element) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (float *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(float));
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: There are no "references" in C

Comment: i get access violation reading location

Comment: The access violation likely means that you have not initialized at least one of the `array[i]` elements. That implies the real error is in how you are reading your floats into the array.

Comment: why is that? if i printed exatly the same thing i did inside the readFunction.

Comment: Pure luck.  You're accessing memory you don't own so anything can happen, including it appearing to work initially and then blowing up in your face later.

Comment: `#include "globals"` in `graph.c` should  be     `#include "globals.h"`

Comment: omg can't believe i'v missed it. That was the problem. I don't know why the compiler didn't give me any error about unkown readedPoints variable. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `readFile` you are using the uninitialized value `nrColumns` and very likely asking to allocate a buffer that's too big, which means that `realloc()` is failing and you are assigning an indeterminate value to `array` as a result.

You need to make sure the `nrColumns` is initialized and you need to test both for a failed read (file is shorter than expected) and a failed memory allocation via `malloc` or `realloc` and handle the error conditions gracefully. That's likely where your error is.

Comment: That is not the problem i think. The for-loop is exactly the same in both the read function in graph.c and init.c. Why should the first pass and the second fail?

Comment: I have allocated enought memory, i use a typeof dynamic array. That's why the readedPoints.used and readedPoints.size. The one holds the number of elements, the second the number of total allocated array size, included the unused ones

Comment: Look at the address of `array` in your debug window there... notice that it is set to 0x3 -- that is **not** a legal memory address. It's pure coincidence that it worked. The behavior is, by definition, "undefined"

Comment: I'll upload the whole read function so you can try to help me.

Comment: please take a look now. I have allocated enougt space for the array. i have used a dynamic growing array

Comment: i still think the problem isn't that one. But probably i'm wrong. I have starting with C only a few days ago. I think the readedPoints is not initialized in that class (init.c) althout i have used extern in the declaration. This is a big mess for my head :p

Comment: The problem was that missing "globals.h" in the 'graph.c' file. It is very weird, the compiler should have gave a an error saying that 'readedPoints' is unknown.

Comment: There's no way it would compile without the header file. Something else was up. But, anyway, it's a moving target and we've already covered it six ways from Sunday.

Comment: Ya you right. My code lacks some consistency as well. Thank you for your help in that.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger says that the value of the pointer is `0x00000003`, that is, three. Three is not the address of a `float` in memory. The only way for a pointer variable to have such a value is if it is uninitialized. Before using `array` you must execute a line such as

```
readedPoints.array = calloc( num_points, sizeof (float) );
```

This would be done along with initializing the other fields

```
readedPoints.size = num_points;
readedPoints.used = 0;
```

Actually Java *does* very much have pointers. It just doesn't have any alternative (so there's no need to mention `*`), and it mostly manages them for you. But even Java requires you to specify the size of a dynamic array. What you've done here is essentially array overflow.

Comment: could you be more specific please? My C knowledge is a little bit limited. You are saying i should use 'calloc' before i'm printing in in 'init.c', which means, use it before i access it in another .c file ? Please look inside the function readFile, i'm using a dynamic growing array

Comment: @JohnHarrod `calloc` (or `malloc`) are like `new` in Java. That is how you specify the size of the array. Accessing the array in any way without allocating memory first by `malloc` or `calloc` is an error.